# Convert separator to enter character

Tags: c#, asp.net

My SQL query retrieves one row of multiple columns. I have stored that in string with '|' separator to differentiate between columns.

And then prints that string in `<textarea>` field of `.aspx` page.

My question is there any way in which after that | separator next column comes in next line in textarea? Just like pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key?

Code:

```
dtOutput = Generix.getData("dbo.EventMsg E Left Join dbo.ATMStatusHistory A On E.Code=A.Fault", "Distinct E.Fault_Short_Name", "A.Code In (" + sFaultNumber + ") And IsNull(Fault_Short_Name,'')<>''", "", "", 1);
sOtherFaults = "";
foreach (DataRow drOutput in dtOutput.Rows)
{
foreach (DataColumn dcOutput in dtOutput.Columns)
{
sOtherFaults += ((sOtherFaults == "") ? "" : ":") + Convert.ToString(drOutput[dcOutput]);
}
}

 sOutput += "|" + sOtherFaults + "|" + sClosedFault + "|" + sTemp + "|";
                            Response.Write(sOutput);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
string.Join(@"|\r\n", sOutput, sOtherFaults, sClosedFault, sTemp);
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont really understand what you mean but try this

```
 sOutput += "|" + sOtherFaults + "|" + sClosedFault + "|" + sTemp + "|";

 Response.Write(sOutput.Replace("|", "\r\n"));
```

Or

```
 sOutput += "|" + sOtherFaults + "|" + sClosedFault + "|" + sTemp + "\r\n";

 Response.Write(sOutput);
```

Comment: I suggest changing `"\r\n"` to `Environment.NewLine`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd be better off using a [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) here, like this.

```
var responseString = new StringBuilder(sOutput);
resposeString.AppendLine("|");

foreach (DataRow drOutput in dtOutput.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn dcOutput in dtOutput.Columns)
    {
        resposeString.AppendFormat("{0}:", Convert.ToString(drOutput[dcOutput]));
    }
}

// Remove last : delimiter
responseString.Remove(responseString.Length - 1, 1);

resposeString.AppendLine("|");
resposeString.Append(sClosedFault);
resposeString.AppendLine("|");
resposeString.Append(sTemp);

Response.Write(responseString.ToString());
```

Like `String.Format` this will save lots of intermediate string instantiations but, also fits nicely in the loop structure.